# need to unserialize an array within an array and print it to a table in php

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, foreach

```
<?php

$data = 'a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:8:"John Doe";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:11:"123 Main St";s:4:"City";s:5:"Dover";s:5:"State";s:2:"DE";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"19904";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-1234";s:5:"Email";s:16:"john@example.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:8:"Jane Doe";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:11:"123 Main St";s:4:"City";s:5:"Dover";s:5:"State";s:2:"DE";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"19904";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-5678";s:5:"Email";s:16:"jane@example.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:15:"Jonny Appleseed";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:15:"1 Infinite Loop";s:4:"City";s:10:"Coopertino";s:5:"State";s:2:"CA";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"90201";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-9101";s:5:"Email";s:15:"jonny@apple.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:12:"Jack Sparrow";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:15:"The Black Pearl";s:4:"City";s:17:"Cut Throat Island";s:5:"State";s:7:"Tortuga";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"00001";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-1213";s:5:"Email";s:14:"jack@savvy.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:14:"Luke Skywalker";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:15:"17 Jedi Council";s:4:"City";s:8:"Corasant";s:5:"State";s:2:"XX";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"99999";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-1415";s:5:"Email";s:17:"luke@theforce.com";}';



$fexplode = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);

foreach ($fexplode as $uline) {
     ?>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="left">
<table>
<?php
    foreach (unserialize($uline) as $item => $value){ 
?>
    <tr>
    <td><b><?php echo $item . ": ";?></b></td>
    <td><?php if ($item == 'Address'){
                    print "Need to print address array here";
                }
                else {
            echo $value;
        }
        ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <br>
 <?php } ?>
 </table>
 <?php } ?>
```

This prints the arrays in a table but when it gets to the address portion with an array within the array it spits out "Array to string conversion" if I replace the 'print "need to print address array here"' with 'echo $value;'

Comment: So check if `$value` is array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `echo $value;`  if $value is a Array, it will show the Notice   "Array to string conversion".

use foreach to echo the Array.

```
if(is_array($value)):
    foreach($value as $value_in):
       echo $value_in;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: After googling answers for an hour it makes me want to cry to find out my problem had such a simple solution. Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Baker2795 if this answer work for you please accept this as a answer.

Comment: because I didn't realize I could. Just did thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Check the item with address value then assign implode it.

```
<td><b><?php echo ($item == 'Address') ? '' : $value." " ;?></b></td>
    <td><?php if ($item == 'Address'){
                    print implode("<br />",$value);
                }
                else {
            echo $value;
        }
        ?> </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$data = 'a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:8:"John Doe";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:11:"123 Main St";s:4:"City";s:5:"Dover";s:5:"State";s:2:"DE";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"19904";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-1234";s:5:"Email";s:16:"john@example.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:8:"Jane Doe";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:11:"123 Main St";s:4:"City";s:5:"Dover";s:5:"State";s:2:"DE";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"19904";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-5678";s:5:"Email";s:16:"jane@example.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:15:"Jonny Appleseed";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:15:"1 Infinite Loop";s:4:"City";s:10:"Coopertino";s:5:"State";s:2:"CA";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"90201";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-9101";s:5:"Email";s:15:"jonny@apple.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:12:"Jack Sparrow";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:15:"The Black Pearl";s:4:"City";s:17:"Cut Throat Island";s:5:"State";s:7:"Tortuga";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"00001";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-1213";s:5:"Email";s:14:"jack@savvy.com";}
a:4:{s:4:"Name";s:14:"Luke Skywalker";s:7:"Address";a:4:{s:6:"Street";s:15:"17 Jedi Council";s:4:"City";s:8:"Corasant";s:5:"State";s:2:"XX";s:3:"Zip";s:5:"99999";}s:5:"Phone";s:12:"555-555-1415";s:5:"Email";s:17:"luke@theforce.com";}';



$fexplode = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);

foreach ($fexplode as $uline) {
     ?>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="left">
<table>
<?php
    foreach (unserialize($uline) as $item => $value){
?>
    <tr>
    <td><b><?php echo $item . ": ";?></b></td>
    <td><?php if ($item == 'Address'){


        foreach ($value as $current_address_data) {
            echo $current_address_data ;

        }

                }
                else {
            echo $value;
        }
        ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <br>
 <?php } ?>
 </table>
 <?php } ?>
```